# Escaping hyphen in yaml key value for Travis CI

Tags: ruby, yaml, travis-ci

Trying to create the test database in the Travis CI build using the `before_script` command as specified here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#using-postgresql-in-your-builds

```
# .travis.yml

before_script:
  - bundle exec rake lint
  - "psql -c 'create database authentication-server_test;' -U postgres"

language: ruby

services:
  - postgresql
```

Travis throws with:

```
$ psql -c 'create database authentication-server_test;' -U postgres
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: create database authentication-server_test;
```

I've done a fair bit of googling and having trouble working out how to escape that hyphen. The sticking point seems to be that I have to wrap the `create database authentication-server_test;` in quotes. Note that the example in the Travis docs has no hyphens.

Any ideas?

Comment: PS I've also tried `- psql -c 'create database authentication-server_test;' -U postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this PostgreSQL identifier:

```
authentication-server_test
```

needs to be quoted so that PostgreSQL won't try to interpret the `-` as an operator. Identifiers are quoted with double quotes so you need to this:

```
"authentication-server_test"
```

into the database. You could escape the double quotes in the YAML:

```
before_script:
  - bundle exec rake lint
  - "psql -c 'create database \"authentication-server_test\";' -U postgres"
```

or drop the outer double quotes (the YAML quotes for the string) while adding the inner double quotes (for the PostgreSQL identifier):

```
before_script:
  - bundle exec rake lint
  - psql -c 'create database "authentication-server_test";' -U postgres
```

or switch to `createdb` about avoid the problem altogether:

```
before_script:
  - bundle exec rake lint
  - createdb authentication-server_test -U postgres
```

by only having to worry about the shell's and YAML's quoting needs (neither of which apply here).

Comment: Thanks man! Was banging my head against a wall for a while on this one. I've seen the double-quotes problem in postgres before but I thought Travis was throwing due to yaml syntax rather than postgres throwing a problem. I've verified your first solution works. Just verifying the second one. Probably won't bother with the third one because a cursory google didn't reveal `createdb` in the travis docs. Maybe you have a link?

Comment: Yes, second one works, too. I've gone with that one because it's neater. Thanks!

Comment: `createdb` is a standard PostgreSQL command: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html. The `psql -c` approach is weird because you have three different things that want to use double quotes (YAML, shell, PostgreSQL), at least the `createdb` one only has two (YAML, shell) and neither needs quotes.